# Listbox automatically updated when pressed Add button

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am making a scheduler application in visual basic and in that there is a add button and a `listbox` below it.The `listbox` has a `datasource` from database and when i press add button some value is to be saved in database and i wanted the same to be reflected in the `listbox` how can i do it??

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention.. Im using VB.net

Comment: It is unclear which challenge you are facing here. Why can't you simply add a click handler for your button that will both push the textbox value into the database and refresh the list?

Comment: What **UI** platform?

Comment: How are you retrieving your data now, just do the same put it in a method, clear the items and then set your new datasource... When you save call the method that will clear the items/datasource and then add the new queried one.

Comment: ive created a button handler and data is pushed into database but it isnt getting showed in the listbox which i wanted to get updated after pressing the button

Comment: ive mentioned ive used datasource as input to listbox from database so its not letting me update any alternative

Comment: You have been asked what UI and kind of datasource.

Comment: @GTARaja, "vb.net" and "datasource as input to listbox from database" is not enough details, sorry. Datasources and listboxes are paradygms that exists in many .NET UI technologies and can all be coded in VB.NET. If you want proper help, you must indicate whether you're making a web application (ASP.NET Webforms / MVC) or a Windows application (Winform, WPF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make a guess and assume you are working with Winforms. :)

In your button click handler you can either:

1. add the record as a new `DataRow` or
2. call the table adapter's `Fill` method again.

If you choose the first way (most performant but might not suit your case), the following MSDN article can help you:

[How to: Add Rows to a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx)

Also, **you may find helpful to review some of the basics concepts of DataSet and general databinding** in Winforms.

- [Data Sources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15.aspx)
- [Binding Controls to Data in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171923.aspx)
- [Editing Data in Datasets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233701.aspx)

I hope you find this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

- Add an item to your data source (it will be added to the list automatically).
- Synchronize your data source to database.

You may want to be doing it the other way around **only if** you find performance bottlenecks with the current approach, i.e. you are adding 1000000 items per second etc.

Comment: i understand the first part but can you explain me about how to synchronize my datasources with database

Comment: @GTARaja it would help to know what type of datasource you're using. Is it a List class? A DataSet? An entity collection?

Comment: @GTARaja: It depends on what your data source is. Could be as easy as calling `AcceptChanges` on your data row/table/set.

Comment: @Crono1981 I have a MS Access Database where im storing some value and the front end is visual basic. ya its a dataset which im using tableadapter.can you help?? Me.SCHEDULETableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataDataSet.SCHEDULE)

Comment: @GTARaja: Please include this information **in the question**. Also while you are at it, please include your data binding code there as well, i.e. how you bind your list to your data source.